# How does Iphone stores and auto-fill passwords/emails in React Native?

Tags: react-native, authentication, expo, autofill, mobile-development

I am building an app in React Native and have 2 screens for SignUp and SignIn. These screens shares the same component(AuthForm) which users type their username and passwords. The below code is my AuthForm:

```
  return(
        <>
        <Spacer>
                <Text h4> {headerText} </Text>
            </Spacer>
            <Input
                label="Email"
                value={email}
                onChangeText={setEmail}
                autoCapitalize={"none"}
                autoCorrect={false}
                autoFocus={true} //If true, focuses the input on componentDidMount. The default value is false.
            />
            <Spacer/>
            <Input
                secureTextEntry={true} //This is for keeping secure, replacing with dots.
                label="Password"
                value={password}
                onChangeText={setPassword}
                autoCapitalize={"none"}
                autoCorrect={false}
            />
            {errorMessage ? <Text style={styles.errorMessage}>{errorMessage}</Text> : null}
            <Spacer>
                <Button title={submitButtonText} onPress={() => onSubmit({email, password})}/>
            </Spacer>
        </>
    );
};
```

And these are my Sign in and Sign up screen screenshots:

[Signin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lz4P9.jpg)

[Signup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tOep.jpg)

As you can see even they use same component for the input, sign Up screen suggests passwords that I used in past, however Sign in screen doesn't has that functionality. How is that possible ?

My package.json:

```
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "eject": "expo eject"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "expo": "^35.0.0",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-dom": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-35.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.3.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.2.0",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^1.10.3",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-expo": "^7.1.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[In RN TextInput docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput) check textContentType. You can set it to `username` or `password` for autofill

Comment: The thing is, it does autofill as I showed the picture of Sign Up page. But I didn't write any textContentType.